# Android Studio: textView.setText(button1.getText()); doesnt work

Tags: gettext, settext

Hey developers out there,

I want to change the text of a textView to the text of a button by clicking the button. I already tried several code but nothing worked, my app is stopping without an error.

This is my code:

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

textView1.setText(button1.getText());
```

Thank you already for your help :)

Edit: It throws IllegalStateException,InvocationTargetException and a NullPointerExcpetion.

Comment: You should provide a minimum, complete, verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you either added the wrong name in the XML or you linked the wrong activity in your onClick()  (the one in the XML view)

The second one is more possible because that causes a crash of your app.

For example, the function getText & the activity getText [MainActivity] are different.

Comment: i only got one activity by now

Comment: Did your app crash only when you click the button?

Comment: yes i already made sure that really this is the code which crashes it, and yeah just by clicking the button and just with this code